# How to get the coordinates of different points in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-scripting

While writing a script, I have to go through a lot of trial and error to simply get a text frame to appear where I want it to be.

The main hurdle is that I can't tell in advance where a `[200, 200]` coordinate will be on the artboard.

Is it possible to, say, hover my mouse on the artboard and get the coordinates of where my mouse is at? Similarly, can I get the distance between two points in the same interactive way? Once I get these values I can use them in my script.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that Illustrator scripting works exclusively in points so your coordinates are in points.. the coordinate system is also different to what you see in Illustrator (depending on AI version, I think)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to open the **Info panel**.

Go `Window > Info`. You'll find the X and Y coordinates for your cursor are shown when nothing is selected. If you select an anchor point, the X and Y coordinates for it are shown instead.